# How to fix a Fatal Runtime Error in C?

Tags: c, loops, runtime-error

I've created a program to read 5 inputs from the user: the amount of money, selection 1, quantity 1, selection 2, quantity 2.
The program is meant to calculate the value of sweets for each of the quantities and take it off the total money, it is required to use some sort of iteration.
I've checked over the code and cannot find any obvious errors however every time I run the program I receive "ERROR: Fatal Runtime Error" there are no other error codes displayed.
My code for the program is below, is there anything that is wrong with the way that I have written the code which is causing the error to come up?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
   int quant, pence, cost, counter = 0;
   double money;
   char candy;
   char output[60] = {0};

   scanf( "%lf %c %d", &money, &candy, &quant );
   pence = (int)(money * 100);

   while( counter < 2 );
    {
    switch (candy)
      {
      case 'a' :
         cost = quant * 55;
         if( pence < cost)
         {
            printf( "You selected %d Mars bars, but do not have enough money", quant );
         }
         else
         {
            pence = pence - cost;
            strcpy( output, "Mars bars" );
         }
         break;
      case 'b' :
         cost = quant * 55;
         if( pence < cost)
         {
            printf( "You selected %d Snickers bars, but do not have enough money", quant );
         }
         else 
         {
            pence = pence - cost;
            strcpy( output, "Snickers bars" );
         }
         break;
      case 'c' :
         cost = quant * 55;
         if( pence < cost)
         {
            printf( "You selected %d Bounty Bars, but do not have enough money", quant );
         }
         else
         {
            pence = pence - cost;
            strcpy( output, "Bounty bars" );
         }
         break;
      case 'd' :
         cost = quant * 85;
         if( pence < cost)
         {
            printf( "You selected %d Peanut M&M bags, but do not have enough money", quant );
         }
         else 
         {
            pence = pence - cost;
            strcpy( output, "Peanut M&M bags" );
         }
         break;
      case 'e' :
         cost = quant * 85;
         if( pence < cost)
         {
            printf( "You selected %d Chocolate M&M bags, but do not have enough money", quant );
         }
         else
         {
            pence = pence - cost;
            strcpy( output, "Chocolate M&M bags" );
         }
         break;
      case 'f' :
         cost = quant * 65;
         if( pence < cost)
         {
            printf( "You selected %d Aero Bubbles bars, but do not have enough money", quant );
         }
         else
         {
            pence = pence - cost;
            strcpy( output, "Aero Bubbles bars" );
         }
         break;
      case 'g' :
         cost = quant * 55;
         if( pence < cost)
         {
            printf( "You selected %d Fruit Pastilles rolls, but do not have enough money", quant );
         }
         else
         {
            pence = pence - cost;
            strcpy( output, "Fruit Pastilles rolls" );
         }
         break;
      case 'h' :
         cost = quant * 55;
         if( pence < cost)
         {
            printf( "You selected %d Wine Gums rolls, but do not have enough money", quant );
         }
         else
         {
            pence = pence - cost;
            strcpy( output, "Wine Gums rolls" );
         }
         break;
      case 'i' :
         cost = quant * 45;
         if( pence < cost)
         {
            printf( "You selected %d Polo Mints rolls, but do not have enough money", quant );
         }
         else
         {
            pence = pence - cost;
            strcpy( output, "Polo Mints rolls" );
         }
         break;
      case 'j' :
         cost = quant * 95;
         if( pence < cost)
         {
            printf( "You selected %d Haribo Gold Bears, but do not have enough money", quant );
         }
         else
         {
            pence = pence - cost;
            strcpy( output, "Haribo Gold Bears bags" );
         }
         break;
      default :
         printf( "%c is an invalid candy selection", candy );
         exit(1);
         break;
      }      
   money = (double)(pence / 100.00);
    printf( "You bought %d %s", quant, output );
   printf( "Change remaining is %0.2lf", money );

   if( counter < 1 )
   {    
      scanf( "%c %d", candy, quant );
   }
   counter++;

   }
}
```

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: 1) `while( counter < 2 );` : remove `;`

Comment: ...and _at least_ one round with debugger may be helpful too... :)

Comment: You may also find compiling with the `-Wall` flag useful.

Comment: 2) `scanf( "%c %d", candy, quant );` --> `scanf( " %c %d", &candy, &quant );`

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Unfortunately after the corrections the error still appears, I will try to run the program through a debugger :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes are there in your code as BLUEPIXY has spotted in your code.

1. Remove the semi-colon in `while( counter < 2 );` to avoid an infinite loop.
2. Add ampersands in

   scanf( "%c %d", candy, quant );
   So that it looks like this

   scanf( " %c %d", &candy, &quant ); //Also note the space before %c
   This is done because `scanf` expects the address of the variable rather than its values to store the user input.

Also remove the `break;` after the `exit(1)` (in the `default` case) as it will never execute. You need to include `stdlib.h` to use `exit`